# My <nav> moves down when I put margin on <header>

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a very simple site. I have a pure CSS Dropdown menu inside my `<nav>` tags. Below the nav, I have my `<header>` tags.

Since I've set my `<nav>` tags to be `position: absolute` my header have naturally moved up, so I apply `margin: 50px 0 0 0` to move it back down. However it appears that my nav moves down with it, and does not clear off from the nav.

I simply don't understand. Firstly, the nav tag is above the header, and is using `position: absolute`.

Here's my code

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
  color: black;
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}

nav {
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
}

header {
  color: white;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}

main {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #000;
}

aside { 
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<nav> 
  <ul>
    <li><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>
    <li><s>About</s></li>
    <li><s>Plugins</s></li>
    <li>Guest
    <ul>
      <li><s>Login</s></li>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<header>
  <h2>Welcome</h2>
</header>

<main>
  <p>Main Content</p>
</main>

<aside>
  <p>Side bar</p>
</aside>
```

Comment: Give your nav a `top:0;` and `left:0;`

Comment: It appears if i use padding on the header that it moves down exactly as i was expecting with margin.

@PatsyIssa Your suggestion seems to work, except I have set my body width to 800px, so having left:0; wornt work as needed.

Comment: You shouldn't set your body width. Use a container inside the body.

Comment: your last </li> and </ul> in the <nav> are incorrectly nested, they're backwards

Comment: Oh dam. Thanks. didnt notice that at all :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, your `nav` element doesn't need to be positioned absolutely. If you want it fixed at the top you could even try use `position: fixed;`.

What I really think you need to do is remove the `position: absolute;`, but if you absolutely need it that way for some reason, add

```
top: 0; 
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

To the `nav` element's CSS.

Also, you should try to use a container, rather than setting the width on your body element, it makes things a lot less flexible the way you're doing it now.

```
.container {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
}
```

(Bit of a strange width to be setting anyway though, why 800px?)

If you can't do that, and you want the nav to still be the width of the body, add `position: relative;` to the body.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, it's named `margin collapse` and is a standart browser behaviour, so to prevent it you can either completely use `padding` or just add `padding-top: 1px;` to your nav element.

```
 nav {
      background-color: #FFF;
      color: #000;
      position: absolute;
      width: 800px;
      padding-top: 1px
}

header {
      color: white;
      margin: 49px 0 0 0;
}
```